# Master Detail doesn't work after orientation change (iPhone 13 Pro Max)

Tags: ios, swiftui, landscape-portrait

## Overview:

- I have a SwiftUI app that shows a master list and a corresponding detail list

## Problem:

- On the **iPhone 13 Pro Max** simulator, when tapped on the master item, the detail is not displayed (see steps to reproduce).

### Specifications:

- Xcode: Version 13.3.1 (13E500a)
- Device: iPhone 13 Pro Max Simulator

## Steps to reproduce:

1. Run the project using the code given in Code section
2. Use app in portrait mode and notice when tapping on each master item, the detail is shown as expected.
3. Rotate the simulator to landscape mode, now again tap on each master item, the detail is shown as expected
4. Rotate the simulator back to portrait mode, now tap on the master item.

## Expected Behaviour:

In step 4, after tapping on master item the detail screen needs to be shown

## Actual Behaviour:

In step 4, after tapping on master item, the cell is selected but doesn't navigate to detail screen. It is stuck in the cell selected state. App doesn't hang but tapping on every cell highlights the cell but doesn't show detail screen.

[image: Step 4 actual Behaviour]

## ScreenRecording Gif

[image: Screen Recording]

## Question:

- What is the problem and how can I fix it?

## Code:

### ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            StudentList()
        }
    }
}
```

### StudentList

```
struct StudentList: View {

    @StateObject var school = School()
    @State private var selectedStudent: Student?

    var body: some View {
        List(school.students, selection: $selectedStudent) { student in
            NavigationLink {
                StudentDetail(student: student)
            } label: {
                Text(student.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### StudentDetail

```
struct StudentDetail: View {
    let student: Student?
    
    var body: some View {
        if let student = student {
            VStack {
                Text("ID  : \(student.id)")
                Text("Name: \(student.name)")
            }
        } else {
            Text("No student selected")
        }
    }
}
```

### School

```
class School: ObservableObject {
    @Published var students = [Student(id: 1, name: "aaa", marks: 100),
                               Student(id: 2, name: "bbb", marks: 83),
                               Student(id: 3, name: "ccc", marks: 42),
                               Student(id: 4, name: "ddd", marks: 92),
                               Student(id: 5, name: "eee", marks: 28)]
}
```

### Student

```
struct Student: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var marks: Int
}
```

Comment: It works fine the first time on portrait mode, but after rotating to landscape and then rotating back to portrait mode it stops working.

Comment: I didn't understand, after rotation (step 4) when selecting the cell, detail doesn't get pushed. (Note the gif is in a loop so it might appear to be working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a SwiftUI bug and should be reported to Feedback Assistant. The `NavigationView` gets stuck in the column style when it should switch back to the stack style.

I have encountered a ton of bugs with the columns style NavigationView style and IMO it should not be used for production in it's current state. You could add `.navigationViewStyle(.stack)` to the NavigationView to force it to stay in stack style and circumvent these problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It is surprising and frustrating that something as basic as orientation change breaks, will file the feedback

Comment: It appears to be a bug in the 13 Pro Max simulator. It doesn't reproduce on the others. Xcode 13.3.1

Comment: @Yrb It's because the Pro Max is big enough to not be in the compact horizontalSizeClass when in landscape and uses the column navigation style while the others do not, they stick to stacked when in landscape. The bug also happens on a real 13 Pro Max.